# Special kind of 1d constrained optimization with Matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to solve the following optimization problem with Matlab: minimize `f(t)` when `t >= 0`.

There's `fseminf` function but i didn't understand well how to apply it to my case. Also it seems a bit overkill to use such a powerful tool for such a seemingly easy problem. I'll be grateful for any tips on how to apply `fseminf` here and any suggestions how else it can be solved.

Comment: I would recomend `fmincon`, a function that lets you specify optimization constraints, algorithms and is well documented.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab is a numerical software so one 'simple' way to solve this problem is to calculate the value of `f(t)` for values of `t>0` and then find the minimum of that. Depending on the function the number of `t`s that you want to evaluate might be smaller or larger.

One possible solution could be:

```
t = 0:0.001:10; % create values from 0 to 10 in steps of 0.001
f = t.^3+5; % evaluate the function for each value of 't'
[minF, locT] = min(f);
minF % this is the smallest value of the function
t(locT) % the minimum value occurred at this 't'
```

You should define `t` to be in the region where you expect the minimum to, if you define it wrong this would only find the local minimum. If the spacing between separate 't's is too large the minimum might also fall between them, that is why I choose a relatively small step of '0.001'.