# Optimization with infinite constraints

Tags: matlab, math, constraints, conditional-statements

I would need to express this condition:

```
a - b(a,x) < 0,         for any a such that     0 < a < Inf
% b(a,x) is a function depending on a and x, the vector to be optimized
% a is an additional variable, of length 1
```

I have come across `fseminf` [function](https://de.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fseminf.html), which seems to be exactly what I was looking to. However, it only takes into account close intervals for 'a'. I would need this constraint to be met for any positive real value of a with a precision of thousandths.

In [another post in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41066868/special-kind-of-1d-constrained-optimization-with-matlab) and in [Matlab documentation](https://de.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fseminf.html) it is mentioned that it is impossible to cover the whole range of positive real numbers, and a guess about which values of `a` are expected must be done. I wonder if there is another way of doing this, because in my case the possible values of `a` do actually depend of another variable `s`, and depending on the value of `s` these values of `a` could vary up to infinity.

Many thanks in advance, and best regards.

Actually the substraction I need to implement is the one above in this image:
[image]

That is, the term of the left in that equality minus the one on the right must be lower than 0 **for any value of `m_u` greater than 0. When the number of iterations (l) tends to infinity, so must do the value of `m_u` --which starts being `0` when `(l)=0`. That is equivalent to say, for any value of `m_u`, the one provided in next iteration should be greater than it.**

The parameters to be optimized in this expresion are `lambda` and `rho`, not `m_u`.

What could I do?

Many thanks in advance and BR.

Comment: If it is, you do not need to come the non linear equation to the optimization. It doesn't make sense anymore!

Comment: I think the question is correct now, thank you for the comments!

Comment: I don't think so!

Comment: What output are you expecting? What do you mean by *making the inequation valid*?  Do you want to find `b` that makes it valid?

Comment: @SardarUsama I expect a boolean. This substraction corresponds to `c` value in nonlinear condition function of fmincon. I just don't know to define the constant `a` not through a single value, but through its whole domain.

Comment: As far as I understand your question, @OmG 's solution is correct. If *that corresponds to `c` value in nonlinear condition*, it means that you want to find optimal value of  `a`

Comment: I would need to define something similar to `a = [0:Inf]`. The problem is that then I would not have one single substraction as a constraint, but a whole set of them, as large as I would decide to partition vector `a`.

Comment: @SardarUsama Question edited. Everything would be diferent if `a` were constrained within a closed interval such as [0,1]. Then you could split `a` as sharp as you'd like and have one different equation for each value of it. Here is slightly different as the interval is no longer closed. This must work for any positive value of `a`.

Comment: OP edited! Tried something new but still does not work out.

Comment: @SardarUsama Usama Heard of one possible function that works out in this case: `fseminf`. The problem is that in the Matlab documentation it only takes values between `[0,1]`, whereas I would it to take any positive real value with an accuracy of thousandths. This would lead to having around 10000 or more constraints in my optimization problem. How could I solve this problem? And another thing is, that the function could (and easily reaches `Inf` value with relative ease, and I don't know how to deal with that. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

First, define a function for nonlinear condition:

```
function [c,ceq] = nonLinear(x)
c = x - b(x);
ceq = [];
```

Then, apply `fmincon` likes the following on target function `f(x)`:

```
fun = @(x)f(x);
nonlcon = @nonLinear;
A = [-1];  % x > 0
b = [0];
Aeq = [];
beq = [];
lb = [];
ub = [];
x0 = [0]; %initial point

[x,fval,exitflag,output] = fmincon(fun,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,nonlcon);
```

Comment: Hello @OmG, thank you for your answer. Is there any other way to do so? Actually this variable `a` is not the one to be optimized, it is defined inside nonlinear condition function. BR!

Comment: So, if it is not in the optimization, it is a constant here! and not related to the optimization!

Comment: You are completely right -my fault. I am correcting the body of the message right now.